# Implement Smart Search with Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api, ef-code-first

I am trying to implement search functionality in my ApiController. What I am trying to do is : To create api for client that will take a single string as input like **"Nike 2016"**. And my api should return records only from **"Nike" brand** and from **"2016" year**.

Below is my model class. **I am using Entity Framework.**

```
class ProductEntity
    {
        public int Year { get; set; }
        public string TAGS { get; set; }
        public Dimension Dimension { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Brand { get; set; }
        public double NumberOfFloors { get; set; }
        public string CostOfBuilding { get; set; }
    }

    class Dimension
    {
        public double length { get; set; }
        public double width { get; set; }
    }
```

I have tried with searching with "or" keyword in all the columns but with that approach I am worried that api is going to be very slow. I want a scalable approach that wouldn't affect performance.

Comment: do you have index by brand and year in your database?

Comment: @Vecchiasignora no. I have just created these two classes. Is it necessary ?

Comment: yes if you have big data in your table it will be slow withoud any indexis on brand and year

Comment: and in you example there will be 'and' not 'or'

Comment: @Vecchiasignora Created indexis. And yes I need 'and' keyword. Can you please give a quick example ? It will be very helpful.

Comment: ok , i will write example bellow as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create filter and initilize it with your filter parametre like this

```
var filter = new Filte {Brand = ..., Year = ....}
........
    public class Filter
        {
            public string Brand { get; set; }
            public int? Year { get; set; }
            public IQueryable<ProductEntity> FilterObjects(IQueryable<ProductEntity> query)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Brand))
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Brand == Brand);
                if (Year.HasValue)
                    query = query.Where(x => x.Year = Year);

            }

        }
```

after it call FilterObjects like this

`var Query = filter.FilterObjects(your dbset of entity);` like this `DbSet<ProductEntity>` or your data access layer db.(member) wich has your `dbset` as `list/enumarable` of `ProductEntity`

and than `Query.ToList()` wich will be real finaly request to your db, and dont forget about indexis

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old question but I thought this might help some ...

Another option might be to use OData which sorting filtering and paging on all entity based endpoints in your entire model.

http://odata.github.io/WebApi/

https://github.com/OData/WebApi